# How to map the Touchscreen Windows Button to right-mouseclick

Tags: autohotkey, gaming, touchscreen, game-controller

My Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro has an extra Windows Touch Button next to the touchscreen.

Is it possible to remap that button to the right mouse button?

This would be very helpful in many games, that are not optimized for touch and rely on using a mouse with two buttons.

Also I think it will be nice to disable the haptic feedback when using it as a right mouse button.

This would be useful for both: Windows an Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is just to remap the left Win-key to the right-mousebutton with Autohotkey.

The manual states how to remap keys: http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm

This is the ahk script to use:

```
; This script replaces the Left Window key and the Window-key next to the Touchscreen on a Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro 
; with the right-Mouse Button. 
; This is extremely useful in many games to play only with the Touchscreen

LWin::RButton
```

I created a [AutoHotkey executable at GitHub](https://github.com/rubo77/Win2rightMouseButton) with the included script ahk2exe inside AutoHotkey

[download Win2rightMouseButton.exe](https://github.com/rubo77/Win2rightMouseButton/raw/master/Win2rightMouseButton.exe)