# Touch-Screen UI Overlay for right-mouse button

Tags: user-interface, gaming, touchscreen

How can I create an overlay that has only one button for right-mouse-click, that always stays on top even in graphical games.

I would like to use that to play some games on my touchscreen, that need a right mousebutton to play.

I already created an [AutoHotkey script to map the Touchscreen Windows Button to right-mouseclick](https://superuser.com/questions/743903/how-to-map-the-touchscreen-windows-button-to-right-mouseclick) But that seems to make some Problems with the resolution of some games.

Answer (score 1):

By "create an overlay" I assume you mean programmatically, because I've never heard of such a thing already available on the market. So, you'd have to write some code.

WPF would be nice for this, I think, but I don't think you can do this in userspace for *fullscreen* apps, just for *windowed maximized* apps. Here's a general idea:

- Make a new WPF project (recommend .NET 4.0 or later).
- Make a window that's [transparent, with no window border](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4208083/420156) and [pass all input events through](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3367137/420156) to the window(s) underneath.
- Apply some slight coloring to a small, non-transparent element (button, etc) on the window so you know where to tap for a right-click. The size and position of the element is up to you.
- Handle the `TouchDown` and `TouchUp` events on the window. If you receive a `TouchDown` and then a `TouchUp` while the `TouchDown` is still occurring, then you can simulate a right mouse click at the location of the first `TouchDown` event. You now have a gesture where you put one finger on the screen where you want to right-click, and another finger on your "right click button", to cause a right click where your first finger was placed.

If you're not up to coding this, it's probably not going to be possible. I certainly don't know of any program that can implement this on full-screen applications which aren't running as windowed maximized.

Comment: OK, that would be cool already, to have the maximized games covered. I will try and see if WPF is easy to understand, and try to program that. thanks.

Comment: It's not very hard to write WPF, especially in this case, if you use the visual designer, and have some experience with GUI programming before (in C#, Visual Basic .NET, F#, etc.) You may run into some sticking points where you need to resort to Windows API (native code) as indicated by one of the answers I linked, but overall it should be feasible, if not particularly easy.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

[TouchMousePointer](http://www.lovesummertrue.com/touchmousepointer/en-us/) - its a virtual on-screen touchpad.

You can use it on the side, or transparent floating or fullscreen.

On windowed games it works floating or on the side, but for fullscreen games it only works correctly with fullscreen mode, then the whole screen simulates a touchpad, meaning that the mouse doesn't go where you tap, but it can be moved by taping and moving anywhere on the screen like on a touchpad.

And a two finger tap results in a right-click.

Perfect workaround for old games!